# Visual Studio linker can't write to [hex number]

Tags: c++, linker, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013

I am getting an error message from Visual Studio's C++ linker:

> error LNK1108: cannot write file at 0xFB296C

The hex value changes with every build. This error doesn't occur on any of my peer's machines, so it's something in my environment.

MSDN suggests that one of the reasons for this error is insufficient disk space, but I have 155 GB free. As far as I can tell, my solution is configured to write all files locally.

Configuring the linker to use /VERBOSE and /LTCG:STATUS, I see that the error occurs towards the end of the run, when it comes time to merge metadata:

> 9>  Finished searching libraries
>   9>  Merging metadata
>   9>  Finished merging metadata
>   9>  LINK : fatal error LNK1108: cannot write file at 0x2E12984

Has anybody encountered this sort of problem before? How can I troubleshoot it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Update 2.

Comment: Is it a network drive?

Comment: No, all local. I'll update my post. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Did you try disabling your Antivirus program?

Comment: Maybe Process Monitor could tell you more about why the file write is failing...?

Comment: Also check permissions on %TEMP%. Try starting VS with elevated privileges to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Praetorian I like that idea.

Comment: @Praetorian, I verified that I have R/W perms to %TEMP%. I cleaned it out while I was in there. Ran VS in admin mode, and the error recurs.

Comment: @drescherjm I actually can't disable my antivirus. I don't have the required permissions on my machine. Corporate IT sucks :P

Comment: Is the file an executable? Are you running the executable while trying to write to it?

Comment: @JustinR. I hate to be the one to propose voodoo crap or to use it but sometimes it works, so did you try restarting your machine ? (hope I'll not get comment-executed for this :) )

Comment: @Scis Actually that's a potential solution. It's possible there's a rogue process still running (linker or even a debug service) that has the file or a portion of the file locked. It's happen to me on many occasions when a debugger crashes.

Comment: @Scis, I just tried restarting. No dice.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I'm having a peek now. It's a bit of a long shot, as VS opens approximately one billion files when linking, but this is a good lead.

Comment: @JustinR. There's a lot of merit to getting the antivirus ruled out. Until you do, you'll always wonder if that's causing the problem by denying the disk write. However, if it IS, it should be logging the attempt somewhere, and give you the option to allow it in the future.

Comment: @JustinR. Also, while I'm thinking of it -- has the link ever succeeded? (Read: did this break recently, or has this never worked?)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I have been able to compile this solution for over a year (you know, when I'm not writing compiler bugs). This appeared unexpectedly. I'm investigating the AV issue now.

Comment: @JustinR. Was the AV installed recently, or recently pull an update in definitions/engine?

Comment: There is no need to disable antivirus completely. Just ask for an exclusion folder (a specific path that is skipped by the antivirus).  Check your antivirus GUI: maybe, you already have all rights needed to configure exclusion folders. If not, explain to IT guys that every day you run the compiler dozens of times; the compiler generates thousands of innocent temporary files, and it makes no sense to check those files. Some tools are known to fail intermittently with antivirus: e.g., git may fail to delete its "index.lock" file because the antivirus locks the file to check it for viruses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to delete the WINMD files within the solution. The fact that the linker was failing to overwrite the merged metadata (according to the log) was the clue. That lead me to reading about Windows Metadata (.winmd) files. I used ILDASM to have a look at the file, and the tool reported that it's corrupt. After deleting the generated winmd files, I am able to compile, link and run normally.

I once had a similar problem with SOU files. Maybe Visual Studio needs a "Super Clean" feature, similar to "Build > Clean Solution" that deletes all generated files.